# flutter widgets inside for loop

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have the following code to create Row widgets based on a returned items from Future Builder

```
 for (int i = 0; i < snapshot.data.length; i++)  Row( ) ,
```

the above will create Rows based on the number of items from `snapshot.data`
what I'm trying to achieve is create multiple widget based on the length of items returned

```
for (int i = 0; i < snapshot.data.length; i++) {
    // for each item create two rows for example 
      Row( ) ,
      Row( ) ,
    }
```

but I get the following error !

```
the element Type 'set<Row>' can't be assigned to the list 'Widget'
```

Comment: so use `for (...) Column(children: [Row(), Row()])` or something like that

Comment: @pskink nice idea thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
List.generate(snapshot.data.length, (index) => Row( ),),
```

or if you want to insert deferent widget at deferent index use:

```
List.generate(snapshot.data.length, (index) {
   if(index == 0){return Row();}
   else if(index == 1){return Column();}
   else{return Container();}
),
```

Answer (score 1):

You either use a `listView.builder` or for in. When you're building a widget you can't use curly braces

Answer (score 1):

Use **ListView.builder** defining the length to **itemCoun**t property.
For Example..

```
body: ListView.builder
  (
    itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
     return Row();
    }
  )
```